Can you undo all edit mode deformations so the mesh returns to its original shape?

The image shows what used to be a cube after i randomly moved its vertices in edit mode. I would like to know if there is a way to just reset edit mode deformations and set the cube to its original shape. In this example I could just Ctrl Z, but i would like to use this for meshes in which this is no longer possible.

No, that's not possible. This is why people in tutorials for example often talk about destructive and non-destructive or procedural workflows. Whatever you do in Edit Mode or when you apply a modifier, this is called a destructive way of modeling because apart from Undo there is no method of reversing the action. Non-destructive workflows are calculated upon an initial base mesh which stays intact "under the hood" and you can return to. Changing something in Edit Mode is changing the initial base mesh to a new initial state on which modifiers etc. build upon.

I imagine you mean something similar to "Clear All Transforms" in Pose Mode.  I do not believe there is such an operation for Edit Mode as it is much more complex.  The closest I can imagine, If you wish to exceed the number of Undo steps that you have preferred, I would suggest the practice of version control / incremental saves.  Save your transformed mesh in increments and name it something meaningful according to that particular transform state and then continue editing.  This way you can always revert to an exact step/form.
